# Что за данные для парсинга твитерра?

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-api

Всем добрый день. Есть скрипт на Python, чтобы парсить ники в Твитере. Но нужно 4 данных: **CONSUMER KEY, CONSUMER SECRET, ACCESS KEY, ACCESS SECRET**. Вот код. Если я хочу парсить к примеру подписчиков не только из своей страницы, а парсить никик подписчиков друга, мне потребуются тогда от него эти данные? Или нет? Заранее большое спасибо!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import time
import re
import codecs, cStringIO
from argparse import ArgumentParser

import tweepy

# Twitter API credentials
consumer_key = "YOUR CONSUMER KEY"
consumer_secret = "YOUR CONSUMER SECRET"
access_key = "YOUR ACCESS KEY"
access_secret = "YOUR ACCESS SECRET"

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)


class UTF8Recoder:
    """
    Iterator that reads an encoded stream and reencodes the input to UTF-8
    """

    def __init__(self, f, encoding):
        self.reader = codecs.getreader(encoding)(f)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next().encode("utf-8")


class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file "f",
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding="utf-8", **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([s.encode("utf-8") for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)


def parse_args():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        '-u',
        '--max_users',
        help='Max amount of followers to return.',
        type=int,
        default=4000,
        metavar='max_users'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-a',
        '--account',
        help='Twitter account to get followers from.',
        type=str,
        metavar='account'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        'file_path',
        help='Input csv file to process.',
        metavar='path'
    )
    return parser.parse_args()


def get_friends_descriptions(api, file_path, twitter_account, max_users):
    """
    Return the bios of the people that a user follows
    api -- the tweetpy API object
    twitter_account -- the Twitter handle of the user
    max_users -- the maximum amount of users to return
    """

    user_ids = []

    try:
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=twitter_account, count=5000).pages():
            user_ids.extend(page)

    except tweepy.RateLimitError:
        print("RateLimitError...waiting 1000 seconds to continue")
        time.sleep(1000)
        for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers_ids, id=twitter_account, count=5000).pages():
            user_ids.extend(page)

    following = []

    for start in xrange(0, min(max_users, len(user_ids)), 100):
        end = start + 100

        try:
            following.extend(api.lookup_users(user_ids[start:end]))

        except tweepy.RateLimitError:
            print("RateLimitError...waiting 1000 seconds to continue")
            time.sleep(1000)
            following.extend(api.lookup_users(user_ids[start:end]))

    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        writer = UnicodeWriter(f)
        for user in following:
            writer.writerow([user.screen_name, user.description])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = parse_args()

    FILE_PATH = args.file_path
    TWITTER_ACCOUNT = args.account
    MAX_USERS = args.max_users

    print("Reading data...")
    get_friends_descriptions(api, FILE_PATH, TWITTER_ACCOUNT, max_users=MAX_USERS)
```